# SFINAE for expressions and decltype(auto)

Tags: sfinae, c++14

Can I mix SFINAE for expressions and decltype auto?

```cpp
template<class T>
auto function() -> decltype(typename trait<T>::test(), auto) {
  return [](){ return T(); };
}
```

Comment: what is decltype(a, b) supposed to mean?

Comment: @StefanoFalasca the expression `(a, b)` uses the built-in command operator. It evaluates `a`, discards the result, then evaluates `b`.  So `decltype(a, b)` has the same type as `decltype(b)` but `a` must be a valid expression

Comment: `decltype(a,b)` is `decltype(expr)`. Inside an expression, you can use the comma operator to do multiple things, e.g. in `for(expr; expr; expr)` you can write `for(...; ...; ++i, ++j)` to increment two indices; the return type of the expression is the return type of the last expression, in this case `decltype(b)`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I rolled back your incorrect edit, auto-return-type deduction is [tag:c++1y] not [tag:c++11]

Comment: I see, thank you. I thought it was an exotic two parameters version of decltype

Comment: Oops, I've just noticed I typed "command operator" in my first comment above, I meant _comma_ operator, but my fingers apparently didn't want to stop typing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can.

The grammar doesn't allow it:

> *decltype-specifier:*
>           `decltype` `(` *expression* `)`
>           `decltype` `(` `auto` `)`

`decltype(expr, auto)` is not a valid *decltype-specifier*, whereas `decltype(auto)` is and it has special meaning as a placeholder type.  The wording is quite specific:

> The type of a variable declared using `auto` or `decltype(auto)` is deduced from its initializer [...] `auto` or `decltype(auto)` shall appear as one of the decl-specifiers in the decl-specifier-seq and the decl-specifier-seq shall be followed by one or more init-declarators, each of which shall have a non-empty initializer.

In C++17 Concepts Lite should make such SFINAE hacks unnecessary anyway, so we won't have to rely on them forever.  You could modify your example to put the SFINAE constraint in a default template argument:

```
template<class T, class Requires = decltype(typename trait<T>::test())>
auto function() -> decltype(auto) {
  return [](){ return T(); };
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a dummy template parameter and either `decltype` or `EnableIf`/`DisableIf`. Thanks for this great answer!

Comment: Concepts Lite will not make it to C++14?

Comment: @TemplateRex, no, the contents of C++14 are already fixed, and don't include Concepts Lite. A separate Technical Specification covering concepts is planned. See http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default template argument SFINAE with function return type deduction though.

```
template<class T, class = decltype(typename trait<T>::test())>
auto function() {
  return [](){ return T(); };
}
```

The downside is that you don't have the parameter names available.